# can't assign to operator in tensor flow for variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having following code. I am beginner to tensor flow.

```
for layer in range(n_layers):
      print("present layer is ", layer)
      with tf.name_scope("layer-%d" % layer):
        'W'+layer = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((d, n_hidden))) ----------> Error here
        'b'+layer = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((1, n_hidden)))
        print("x_hidden shape {} and W shape {}".format(x.shape, 'W'+layer.shape))
        x_hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, 'W'+layer) + 'b'+layer)
        # Apply dropout
        x_hidden = tf.nn.dropout(x_hidden, keep_prob)
        x = x_hidden
        d = n_hidden
```

Above code error is shown

```
 File "<ipython-input-8-c114e61ddb3f>", line 49
    'W'+layer = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((d, n_hidden)))
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

I want to have dynamic weight variable name according to layer i.e, W1, W2, etc and want to it later. How can I achieve this.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict` for that

```
with tf.name_scope("layer-%d" % layer):
    d = {'W'+layer: tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((d, n_hidden))),
         'b'+layer: tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((1, n_hidden)))}

    x_hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, d['W'+layer]) + d['b'+layer])
```

But I don't know why would you like to do it, the variables seem to be used only inside the `for` loop, just use the same name

```
with tf.name_scope("layer-%d" % layer):
    W_layer = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((d, n_hidden))),
    b_layer = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((1, n_hidden)))}
```